# How to convert string into a date format in spark

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, dataframe

I have passed a string (`datestr`) to a function (that do ETL on a dataframe in spark using scala API) however at some point I need to filter the dataframe by a certain date 
something like :

```
df.filter(col("dt_adpublished_simple") === date_add(datestr, -8))
```

where `datestr` is the parameter that I passed to the function.

Unfortunately, the function `date_add` requires a column type as a first param.
Can anyone help me with how to convert the param into a column or a similar solution that will solve the issue?

Comment: thanksss that works as charm

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez : pls go ahead and post it as answer.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably only need to use [`lit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions%24@lit(literal:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to create a *String* **Column** from your input *String*. And then, use [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@to_date(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fmt:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to create a *Date* **Column** from the previous one.

```
df.filter(col("dt_adpublished_simple") === date_add(to_date(lit(datestr), format), -8))
```